# Condition for two common tangents

Tags: geometry, circles, tangent-line

Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be the centres of two circles, $r_1$ and $r_2$ be their radii respectively. I know that the condition for the existence of four common tangents between the two circles is $r_1 + r_2 < C_1C_2$. Similarly, the condition for only three common tangents is $r_1 + r_2 = C_1C_2$. Both these conditions are pretty obvious.

Now, the condition for the existence of (only) two common tangents between the two circles is $|r_1 - r_2| < C_1C_2<r_1 + r_2$, and the condition for no common tangents is $C_1C_2 < |r_1 - r_2|$. How are these two conditions derived?
[image]

Comment: If the circles are $$(x-a_1)^2+(y-b_1)^2=r_1^2, (x-a_2)^2+(y-b_2)^2=r_2^2.$$

The dual conics intersect as $$\langle p_4(y),c x+q_3(y)\rangle$$

The $p_4(y)$ splits into two factors of degree 2, and their discriminants are

$$-4(a_1r_2-a_2r_1)^2((r_2-r_1)^2-((b_2-b_1)^2+(a_2-a_1)^2)), -4(a_1r_2+a_2r_1)^2((r_2+r_1)^2-((b_2-b_1)^2+(a_2-a_1)^2))$$

From which you get cases on the signs.

Comment: I think that if you understand that two circles are tangent externally iff $C_1C_2=r_1+r_2$, and that two circles are tangent internally iff $C_1C_2=|r_1-r_2|$, then you should be able to understand the other three cases easily.